# Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rse

When I try to connect to some ssh server using Eclipse (which used to work smoothly before), it gives me this error:

> Failed to connect sshd on "x.x.x.x": ProxySOCKS5: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection refused

N.B. The ssh connection is working from the shell with no problems.

Comment: Please let me know guys if you need any supportive information to help you solving this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it :))

It was a proxy problem, I wasn't aware of that!!

Go to `Window - > preferences - > General -> Network`. Make the `Active Provider` -> `Direct`, where all the `proxy entries` are unchecked.

Comment: Having all this trouble, went from flatpak to manual download just to update, 2023-09 (4.29) version, Fedora Linux.  The network connection was set to Native by default.  Changed to Direct.  Tried a Maven project update.  Still getting this darn SOCKS proxy error, when they are all unchecked and empty, also when importing the existing project. Even restarted the application after changing this too.  My OS networking is fine, no proxy there, and Eclipse even updated successfully....